# Javascript validation to check number range not working for 4 digit numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate numbers entered between two text boxes for their range where first number cannot be greater than the second number. The validation works for numbers with three digits (for ex. 800 - 900), when i try to enter 800 - 1000 it returns false even if this case is valid.
My code goes here:

```
    function validate_range(num1,num2)
    {
       if(num2<num1)
       {
          alert("Invalid range");
          return false;
       }
    }
```

I am not able to figure out why this happens. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you're entering *numbers* and not *strings*?

Comment: If `num1` and `num2` are strings then they are compared using the dictionary order (`1000` comes before `900` in the dictionary). You may want to learn about the [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) Javascript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parseInt is your friend

```
console.log(4444 < 9999); // true
console.log('4444' < '9999'); // false
console.log(parseInt('4444') < parseInt('9999')); // true
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. Solved.

Answer (score 2):

This would happen when you are comparing strings instead of numbers

```js
console.log(800 < 1000);
console.log('800' < '1000');
```